# I'm using pycharm to try and talk to my Arduino with pyserial. If i give 0 input led is off if i give 1 then led should on

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyserial, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am doing this code in pycharm for serial communication between arduino and pytharm using python 3 version:

```
import serial  # add Serial library for Serial communication
ser=serial.Serial('com8',9600)
while(1):
    val= raw_input('Enter value');
    if val== '1':
        print'Led is on'
    elif val=='2':
        print'fan is on'
    elif val=='3':
        print'fan is off'

else:
    print'Led is off'
ser.write(val)
```

The below code in arduino for serial communication

```
{ 
      Serial.begin(9600); 
      pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
   }
 
void loop(){ 
   if(Serial.available())
   {
    switch(Serial.read()){
      case '0':
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    break;
    case '1':
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    break;
    case '2':
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    break;
    case '3':
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    break;
    }
   }
   }
```

And i am getting this erroe in pycharm while doing this code

```
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectsimple\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectsimple\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial("COM8",9600)
TypeError: Serial() takes no arguments

Process finished with exit code 1
```